# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_8" is incompatible with the layer - deep learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to setup my first deep learning sequential model with a small test dataset.

Unfortunately, I get the following error message when I call model.fit():

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_8" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 160, 4000), found shape=(32, 4000)
```

My model is as follows

```
num_of_classes = 2
input_shape = (1,4000)

y_train_cat = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_of_classes)
y_test_cat = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_of_classes)



model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=10, kernel_size=5, input_shape=(160, 4000)))
model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The data is of the following dimensions

```
x_train.shape is (160, 4000)


y_train_cat is (160, 2)
```

There are two classes.

Thank you for reading this far and your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give a layer the shape, is supposed to be the same of a single sample... change

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=10, kernel_size=5, input_shape=(160, 4000)))
```

to

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=10, kernel_size=5, input_shape=(4000,1)))
```

and it should work fine

Edit:
You probably also need to reshape your input to add a dimension:

```
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, 2)
```

Explanation:
consider a single element, a 1D convolution "slides" a 1D filter over your 1D element, however you can assume to have multiple channels, thus the leading "1" in the shape of the input

[image]